# Affects of removing a merge commit from a feature branch in a feature branch that will both be merged in

Tags: git, git-merge, git-revert, reverting

In short, I have merged in changes from a feature branch onto my current feature branch, and have pushed the merge remotely, creating a merge commit with the changes I merged in. Now, the problem is, I didn't need these changes. Also, these changes have broken my builds, because I will need to merge in changes from other projects on my current feature branch. I want to avoid doing this, so I want to revert the merge commit.

```
Two feature branches, b1 and b2.
Merged b1 into b2, creating merge commit mc1, on b2.
Want to revert mc1 on b2.
Afraid revert mc1, will affect the merge of b1 into master staging.
```

I am afraid because I feel like the revert, will obviously have the changes that remove the stuff I merged in from b1, which could remove those changes from master once both branches have been merged into master...

Comment: Did you remove the original branch `b1`? If not, your changes prior to `mc1` should still be present in `b1`, allowing you to revert `b2` safely

Comment: How to revert a commit: https://code.likeagirl.io/how-to-undo-the-last-commit-393e7db2840b

Comment: @wcarhart No branches have been deleted. I haven't merged in either branch, and will be merging b1 into master around the same time as b2, well as soon as I verify both, they will both be merged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you haven't removed your previous branch `b1`, you should be able to safely revert commits on `b2` without losing any changes that were present on `b1`.

You can revert commits with:

```
git revert <commit hash>
git checkout <current branch>
```

Read more about reverting commits [here](https://code.likeagirl.io/how-to-undo-the-last-commit-393e7db2840b).

As for conflicts with `master`, `master` will only have changes that are merged in. If you merge *only* `b1` into `master`, `master` will have the changes from `b1`. If you merge *only* `b2` into `master`, `master` will have the changes from `b2`. If you merge `b1` *and* `b2` into `master`, you may have to resolve any merge conflicts that arise, but `master` will then contain the resolved changes from `b1` and `b2`.